# My function is not working some wierd reason, not sure why

Tags: c, pointers

I am making this university project. Basically what i have to do is to work with text file. Function emptyLineCounter() is supposed to count empty lines in file. When called in v() it does what it is supposed to, later on, i call the function inside n(). This is where it fails and returns segmentation error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSIZE 100

void checkArrayStatus() {
    //check if dynamic arrays (dynamicke polia) are created
}

int checkFileStatus(FILE *file, const char *filename) {
    //checks if file is open or close
    if (file != NULL) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("Neotvoreny subor %s\n", filename);
        return -1;
    }
}

int emptyLineCounter(FILE *file) {
    //empty lines counter; number of empty lines == number of meassurments done
    int emptyLineCount = 1; //maybe rework this, doesn't count last line
    char line[MAXSIZE];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {
        int isEmpty = 1; //assume line empty
        for (int i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (line[i] != ' ' && line[i] != '\t' && line[i] != '\n' && line[i] != '\r') {
                isEmpty = 0; // Line is not empty
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isEmpty) {
            emptyLineCount++;
        }

    }

    return emptyLineCount;
}

FILE* v() {
    //declare files as empty values
    FILE *dataloger = NULL;

    char *output[] = {"ID. mer. modulu:", "Pozícia modulu:", "Typ mer. veliciny:", "Hodnota:", "Cas merania:", "Datum merania:", ""};

    //if files not opened try to open them
    while (checkFileStatus(dataloger, "dataloger.txt") == -1) {
        dataloger = fopen("dataloger.txt", "r");
    }  

    if (1) { //change condition to false if n not pressed, use pointers probably
        char line[MAXSIZE];
        int pos = 0;
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), dataloger) != NULL) {
            if (pos == 7) {
                pos = 0;
            }
            printf("%s ", output[pos]);
            printf("%s", line);
            pos++;

        }
    }

    int measurement = emptyLineCounter(dataloger);

    return dataloger;
}

int n(FILE **file) {
    rewind(*file);
    if (checkFileStatus(*file, "dataloger.txt") == -1) {
        printf("Checking ... Failing\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("passed\n");

    printf("HERE: %d", emptyLineCounter(*file));//length of array based on number of measurmenets

    /*
    int dim1 = 3;
    int dim2 = 6; // Number of "inner" arrays
    char ***dynamicArray = (char ***)malloc(dim1 * sizeof(char **));

    //rework so that it accepts each line instead of input
    for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
        dynamicArray[i] = (char **)malloc(dim2 * sizeof(char *));
        for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {
            dynamicArray[i][j] = (char *)malloc(256 * sizeof(char)); // Assuming a maximum string length of 255 characters
            printf("Enter a string for element [%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%s", dynamicArray[i][j]);
        }
    }*/
    return 0;
}

void c() {
    printf("c\n");
}

void s() {
    printf("s\n");
}

void h() {
    printf("h\n");
}

void z() {
    printf("z\n");
}

int main() {
    //char to store user option
    char opt;

    FILE *v_val = NULL;
        
    //while true keep running -> end at option k
    while(1) {

        scanf("%s", &opt);

        switch(opt){
            //two cases to include capital/lowercase letters
            case 'v':
            case 'V':
                v_val = v();
                //printf("%p", v_val);
                break;
            case 'n':
            case 'N':
                n(&v_val);
                break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                c();
                break;
            case 's':
            case 'S':
                s();
                break;
            case 'h':
            case 'H':
                h();
                break;
            case 'z':
            case 'Z':
                z();
                break;
            case 'k':
            case 'K':
                printf("end\n");
                //fclose(v_val);
                return 0;
            default:
                printf("Nesprávna možnosť\n"); //check for what the output should be
                break;
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out why the function suddenly doesn't work. I suspected that it was connected to pointers that i use when passing them between v <-> main <-> n but didn't find any mistake there.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &opt);` You cannot read a string into a single character. Use `%c` instead.

Comment: It is possible (not sure how likely that is) that overflow on `opt` variable corrupts the file pointer between calling `v` and `n`. You should try to run your program in a debugger and watch variable contents while stepping through your code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your code.  And as noted in the good comments, it appears the issue is as simple as attempting to read in a character in the "scanf" function but signifying a character array (string).

```
scanf("%s", &opt);
```

In testing out your code (FYI, I refactored the literal verbiage to English) I was able to replicate the segmentation fault.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Empty/bin/Release$ ./Empty 
Enter option: v
Unopened file dataloger.txt
ID. Measurement module: Module #1
Module position: 1
Type of measure quantities: Kilograms
Value: 80
Time of measurement: 10:00:00
Date of measurement: 25-Oct-2023
 
The empty line count when opening the file is: 1
Enter option: n
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Changing the scanf function to the following statement seemed to address the issue.

```
scanf(" %c", &opt);
```

Note the space before "%c".

Here is a retest of the code.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Empty/bin/Release$ ./Empty 
Enter option: v
Unopened file dataloger.txt
ID. Measurement module: Module #1
Module position: 1
Type of measure quantities: Kilograms
Value: 80
Time of measurement: 10:00:00
Date of measurement: 25-Oct-2023
 
The empty line count when opening the file is: 1
Enter option: n
passed
HERE: 1
Enter option: n
passed
HERE: 1
Enter option: k
end
```

So always be cognizant of the data type being used as the receiver variable when utilizing the "scanf" function.